# SQL Update Statement not working but the information from row=fetch_assoc() are printed on the screen

Tags: php, sql, database

I am looping through the rows of the database with fetch_assoc() and I am selecting two columns of it. I check the values of these two columns of each row. If they are between 2 values then I updated a third row as 1(TRUE) if a statement is true. I am creating two connections because there are two statements, the one that selects the information and the other that updates the column that I want to be updated. When I try to print the information in the screen it seems that the SELECT statement works but when I try to UPDATE the column that I want the UPDATE statement does not update the database. Here is my code:

```
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root");        

$variablech = 1 ;   

$query = "SELECT Client, Info FROM DataTable";


if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {

while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

    if((($row['Client']>=54.055) && ($row['Client']<=54.117) ) && (( $row['Info']>=-4.827) && ( $row['Info']<=-4.317)))
   {
    $variablech = 0;

    $sql=  " UPDATE DataTable SET InfoData='$variablech' WHERE Client='".$row['Client']."' AND Info='".$row['Info']."'";
    $conn->query($sql);
    echo "yes";
  }

  else
  {
    $variablech = 1;
    $sql=  " UPDATE DataTable SET InfoData='$variablech' WHERE Client='".$row['Client']."' AND Info'".$row['Info']."'";
    $conn->query($sql);

   echo "no";


  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
...
$sql=  "UPDATE DataTable SET InfoData='".$variablech."' WHERE Client='".$row['Client']."' AND Info='".$row['Info']."'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
...
```

### Suggestion:

Not sure, if you have an `auto_increment` field in your table. If you do, then select it in `select` query and then use the same to update the data in `update` query. That will speed up the database stuff and so is your project.